# How to manage css media query grid columns

Tags: html, css

I have 12 gallery thumbnails. How do I specify 4 media queries allowing only 6, 4, 3, or 2 columns while maintaining proportionate image scaling and equal margins at 10px between each thumbnail without causing the media query column rule to break? for example at min-width: 1000px it currently displays 5 columns instead of 6

```
    <main class="gallery">
<a href="#"><img src="https://cdn0.wideopenpets.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/snake-in-hats-11feature-image-770x405.png" alt="" class="ctrl" id="btn-1"></a>    
<a href="#"><img src="https://i2.wp.com/metro.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/party-snake.jpg?quality=90&strip=all&zoom=1&resize=644%2C427&ssl=1" alt="" class="ctrl" id="btn-6"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQk4j0EKreALTRlYkyIP8kLHfjY-1FcxUuyzjlv3pu2Uh_cdlu1&s" alt="" class="ctrl" id="btn-2"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="https://ball-pythons.net/forums/cache2.php?img=https://41.media.tumblr.com/7f75b21e7edcc2adc45e4eb2f82a362a/tumblr_o52rt6NTRH1s9amz4o7_1280.jpg" alt="" class="ctrl" id="btn-7"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="https://static.boredpanda.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/cute-snakes-wear-hats-110__700.jpg" alt="" class="ctrl" id="btn-3"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="https://www.thesun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/NINTCHDBPICT000516637716.jpg" alt="" class="ctrl" id="btn-8"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="https://cdn0.wideopenpets.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/snake-in-hats-11feature-image-770x405.png" alt="" class="ctrl" id="btn-4"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="https://i2.wp.com/metro.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/party-snake.jpg?quality=90&strip=all&zoom=1&resize=644%2C427&ssl=1" alt="" class="ctrl" id="btn-9"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQk4j0EKreALTRlYkyIP8kLHfjY-1FcxUuyzjlv3pu2Uh_cdlu1&s" alt="" class="ctrl" id="btn-5"></a>
<a href="#"> <img src="https://ball-pythons.net/forums/cache2.php?img=https://41.media.tumblr.com/7f75b21e7edcc2adc45e4eb2f82a362a/tumblr_o52rt6NTRH1s9amz4o7_1280.jpg" alt="" class="ctrl" id="btn-10"></a>
<a href="#"> <img src="https://static.boredpanda.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/cute-snakes-wear-hats-110__700.jpg" alt="" class="ctrl" id="btn-11"></a>
<a href="#"> <img src="https://www.thesun.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/NINTCHDBPICT000516637716.jpg" alt="" class="ctrl" id="btn-12"></a>
```

```
    .gallery{
 background: white;
 width: 100%;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(150px, 1fr) );
 grid-gap: 10px;
 align-items: start;
 justify-items: center;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 40px 40px 40px;}

 img {
 background: lightblue;
 box-shadow: none;
 border-radius: 5px;
 width:15vw;
 height:10vw;
 max-width: 100%;
  }
 .ctrl:active{
 box-shadow: 0em 0em .5em rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 }
 .ctrl:hover{
 box-shadow: 0em 0em .5em rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 }
 .ctrl:focus{
 box-shadow: 0em 0em .5em rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 }
 @media screen and (max-width : 505px ) {
 .grid {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-direction: row;}
 .cell {
 width: 50%;
 margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;}}
 @media ( min-width : 505px ) and (max-width : 800px ) {
 .grid {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-direction: row; }
 .cell {
 width: calc(100% / 3);
 margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 }
 }
 @media (min-width : 800px ) and ( max-width : 1000px) {
 .grid {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-direction: row;
 }
 .cell {
 width: calc(100% / 4);
 margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;} }

 @media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
 .grid {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-direction: row;}
.cell {
 width: calc(100% / 6);
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;}}
```

Comment: Read up on flexbox. That's the ticket - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @IskandarRezaRazali I'm still struggling to understand how to specify spacing between responsive sized content while also specifying the number of columns allowed. When I try to do both the column specification breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep flexbox to the rescue, hat tip to [Nikk Pearce's codepen](https://codepen.io/nikkpearce/pen/xgZRjY), which I then [edited to fit your situation](https://codepen.io/dirtandrust/pen/NWWMxRm). Add spacing between elements and styling as needed from here.

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.responsive-image {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.cell img {
  display: block;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .cell {
    width: 50%;
        padding: 1em;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .cell {
    width: calc(100% / 4);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="cell">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/800x800" class="responsive-image">
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/800x800" class="responsive-image">
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/800x800" class="responsive-image">
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/800x800" class="responsive-image">
    </div>
     <div class="cell">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/800x800" class="responsive-image">
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/800x800" class="responsive-image">
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/800x800" class="responsive-image">
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/800x800" class="responsive-image">
    </div>
       <div class="cell">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/800x800" class="responsive-image">
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/800x800" class="responsive-image">
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/800x800" class="responsive-image">
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/800x800" class="responsive-image">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This helped, however when I tried to leaving spacing between each thumbnail by adding 10px margins to .cell in css it breaks leaving a large gap to the side and doesn't follow the column rules?

Comment: Hi what was needed was box-sizing: border box then you can add padding to each cell without adding width, now it works.

Comment: this causes the image to not fill entire cell area

Comment: Hi @LASO either resize your images to squares or set them as background images on each div with a % width and height: auto.

Comment: @nathanial Flick Thank you...I'm not sure I understand: I want to keep a 3:2 ratio instead of square so i added id's to all .cell divs and moved the 12 imgs from html to css as background imgs with their corresponding id and now nothing shows?

Comment: @nathanial Flick I figured out the image fill issue and spacing, but it fails when trying to apply spans to get a 3:2 ratio <li> https://jsfiddle.net/enbduLj3/

Comment: Don't apply spans, size the div that contains the image at the ratio you desire. Alternatively, make sure all the images are the same size and ratio and use those instead and you don't have to worry about sizing the div around them.